# Metadata to encapsulate migrated questions

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, migration

Is there now, without feature-requests, a way to set migrated posts as categories to hide or display?  If there is no direct feature, can it be done by

> adding a tag like [migrated-to-mse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrated-to-mse) to questions moved to MSE from other sites, or [migrated-to-meta.mse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrated-to-meta.mse) for things that land on the meta site?

This would allow a user to Ignore things that are out-migrated when reading the originating site, and to handle migrated material in searches.

Comment: Probably someone with some time to kill could create a script based on the presence of `[migrated]` at the end of the title.

Comment: If you search for `is:question migrated:no` it will return all questions which have not been migrated away from the current site. I am unaware of any simpler way of filtering out questions which have been migrated.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but it seems that it is not possible to edit the original post after the migration, check for example [this migrated question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11752/approach-question-prove-that-n-n?noredirect=1). If this is true, we can't manually add a tag flaging the post as migrated after it has been migrated.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Migrating a question closes ***and locks*** it.  (See the "When Should This Not Be Used" section [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32515/214632).)

Comment: @ArthurFischer If a question is locked, are mods still able to edit it? (But even if they can do that, this does not seem as a very good workaround, since it increases workload on mods.)

Comment: @Martin: Yes, mods can edit, retag, comment on, etc. locked posts.  (But I wouldn't really want to have to handle such a tag. Adding it in appropriate cases and searching for cases when it has been improperly added would be a bit of a drag on the mods.)

Comment: The only thing I was able to find on meta.SO which seemed relevant to hiding migrated questions was this feature request: [Tag closed/migrated question instead of or in addition to modifying the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109807/tag-closed-migrated-question-instead-of-or-in-addition-to-modifying-the-title). One of the answers suggest using search to hide them.
I have also [asked in a chatroom](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1642242#1642242) on meta.SO, but I have not received other suggestion than using search.